# logic errors with print the sum of all the numbers that are either multiple of three or five

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I'm having some logic errors with my program. I've been trying to solve this for the last couple of hours. It's supposed to print the sum of all the numbers that are either multiple of three or five.

my output

```
1.)enter an integer number (0 to end): enter an integer number (0 to end):
2.)enter an integer number (0 to end): 3+ = 3
```

expected output

```
1.)enter an integer number (0 to end): 3 = 3
2.)enter an integer number (0 to end): 3+5 = 8
```

below is my code.

```
while True:
  answer = ""
  num = int(input("enter an integer number (0 to end): "))
  end_answer = 0

  if num == 0:
    exit()

  for i in range(1, num+1):
    if i%3==0 or i%5==0 :
      answer += str(i)
      end_answer += i


    if i != num and (i%3==0 or i%5==0):
      answer += "+"
      print(str(answer) + " = " + str(end_answer) )
```

I've seen similar answers for this just not in python specifically

Comment: `while True:` doesn't have an exit condition, and no break. Your code will keep asking for `num` forever (assuming empty lines end code block which had to be formatted)

Comment: Please format your code correctly, it won't run in its current state. @TusharAggarwal, I'm guessing the correct indentation would have the whole *thing* inside the `while True`, meaning that the `if num == 0: exit()` would be the exit condition.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes that is correct if the number is equal to zero it exists.

Comment: @AngelValenzuela, you still need to properly format the indentation

Comment: hopefully, my indentation is correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following (properly indented) code will give you what you need:

```
while True:
    num = int(input('Enter an integer number (0 to end): '))
    if num == 0: exit()

    answer = ''
    end_answer = 0
    sep = ''
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 :
            answer += sep + str(i)
            sep = ' + '
            end_answer += i

    if end_answer > 0:
        print(str(answer) + ' = ' + str(end_answer) )
```

Note that it uses a variable separator `sep` to more cleanly print the item you're working out. A sample run follows:

```
Enter an integer number (0 to end): 2
Enter an integer number (0 to end): 3
3 = 3
Enter an integer number (0 to end): 10
3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 = 33
Enter an integer number (0 to end): 38
3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 12 + 15 + 18 + 20 + 21 + 24 + 25 + 27 + 30 + 33 + 35 + 36 = 329
Enter an integer number (0 to end): 0
```

Comment: so was my issue that my indentation was wrong and that's why it was giving me a wrong output?

Comment: @AngelValenzuela: no idea. If your indentation was *really* what you originally had, it never would have run at all! So I thought it easier just to provide something that *would* run, based on your textual description.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code a lot by using the `sum` builtin and *f-strings* for printed text formatting. This will likely be more efficient as well.

### Code

```
from itertools import count

counter = count(1)

while True:
    num = int(input(f'{next(counter)}). Enter an integer number (0 to end): '))

    if num == 0:
        break

    nums = [x for x in range(1, num + 1) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0]
    print(f'{" + ".join(map(str, nums))} = {sum(nums)}')
```

### Output

```
1). Enter an integer number (0 to end): 3
3 = 3
2). Enter an integer number (0 to end): 9
3 + 5 + 6 + 9 = 23
3). Enter an integer number (0 to end): 15
3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 12 + 15 = 60
4). Enter an integer number (0 to end): 0
```